# ReactDOMServer is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using pre-built browser builds of React and ReactDOM v15 from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html) since I can't use npm in a given project.

I need to use `renderToString` from the react-dom/server but I'm getting `ReactDOMServer is not defined` error.

`React` and `ReactDOM` are fine. Any idea how I can access `ReactDOMServer`?

Comment: do you have var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server'); and ReactDOMServer.renderToString(ReactComponent); ? it will not work if you don't use npm...

Answer (score 3):

Cause you haven't imported it. Add this

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
```

If react-dom/server not found then you need to npm install it

`npm install react react-dom`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after running into this issue myself and trying to find ReactDOMServer somewhere, I almost gave up and was looking for the source directly and about to Browserfiy when like 10 answers down in Google I saw the cdnjs libaries and lo and behold:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react/

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.0/react-dom-server.min.js

So I guess they have it built there, and so there you go, you can include it wherever you like, like JSBin as I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

In my bundles file I had to import:

```
//= require react-dom/static/react-dom-server
```

Then I was able to import ReactDOMServer from react-dom/server without a problem.